# AVPlayer smooth scrubling remote video (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, http-live-streaming

I have set of mp4 files (~ 130 mb each, so I cant put those files inside app bundle) which I need to scrub smoothly without jumping in my app. Is there any way to achieve it?

I have tried to use HLS via vimeo, but it still lose some frames during scroll. Also tried to predownload hls via AVAssetDownloadUrlSession, scroll works good but it takes to long to download asset with good quality.

Thanks in advance